# How warm are rain drops?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, water, atmospheric-science

I thought of this question after a week of jogging, where each day after it rained, the temperature seemed warmer. I also noted this as a lifeguard where, after closing the pool due to thunder, we would go for a swim and the downpour actually seemed to warm the pool.

I haven't really attempted much prior research as the whole phenomenon seems to be influence by a number of variables I may be blind to or lack complete knowledge of. Such as

- How humidity may play into this
- Whether the drops begin to burden the cloud after a certain part turns into liquid form or the mass together is cooled and weighted as so
- How air density may play a role into this
- Types of Water and acidity
- Energy exposed to
- Polarity

Comment: That part about *haven't really attempted much prior research* is actively discouraged and could get your question closed as *low quality*.  See [the rules on how to ask a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Not a meteorologist so this is a at best a first order approximation, or some things you might want to look into.A single raindrop has a fairly negligible mass wrt to its surface area, also the air is fairly saturated with water as it rains. Therefore the rain drop itself is probably at a thermal equilibrium with the atmosphere (i.e. same chemical potential, temperatures, ect). However, rain needs water to condensate from vapor. This releases heat, which will warm up the atmosphere.  Therefore, it should be warmer after rain. However met. has thousands of variables so this is a 1st approx.

Comment: If no answers arise here, you may want to try over at [earthscience.se]

Comment: "*as a lifeguard where, after closing the pool due to thunder, we would go for a swim*" 

Comment: this post ( https://www.thoughtco.com/what-determines-rain-temperature-3443616 ) says that the temperature of rain drops can be anywhere between 0-27 Celsius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be caused by the body not feeling warmer in the water (in the pool case), but feeling colder outside the water. Your body feels the larger temperature difference and falsely assumes this to imply higher water temperature.

When it rains (and when the wind blows) evaporation happens more rapidly from your humid skin. It will feel much colder than otherwise.

Apart from that, the humidity of the air, wind speed etc all play a role in the so-called "chill effect". I cannot speak for other countries, but here in little cozy (and rainy and windy)  Denmark, our weather forecasts often inform us of the chill factor as a measure of how cold it *feels* for the average person under the conditions of that day.

I cannot say for sure that these considerations are the case in your situation. That will require some more detail. But they might give a hint.